# "kubectl logs" not working after adding NAT gateways in GCE

Tags: kubernetes, google-compute-engine, nat, google-kubernetes-engine

What I did is follow the instructions in the section of "Build high availability and high bandwidth NAT gateways" in https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/special-configurations, and after I tagged all instances with "no-ip", I was no longer able to access the pod logs using "kubectl logs".

Is it because `kubectl logs` under the hood using ssh? Is there any workaround to see the pod log?

Comment: it should still work, kubectl logs interacts with the k8s api-server on your master, the master then retrieves logs from the container (effectively running docker logs on the node) and sends the info back to you. What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: Also, is kubectl logs the only command that fails?

Comment: @PatrickW "kubectl logs" and "kubectl exec" both failed. I was expecting that "kubectl exec" would fail, because it uses ssh underthehood, and I know that sshing into a node using its public IP would fail once that node's outbound connections go through NAT.

Comment: anytime you run a kubectl command it interacts with the API server on the master. The master then connects to the node using SSH. I think we need more details about how you have your infrastructure setup (more details about the NAT and what traffic is directed through it)

Comment: @PatrickW I see, currently outbound connections from my nodes ALL go through the NAT gateway, which might be the reason the master couldn't ssh into the nodes. I'll experiment adding a route rule so that outbound connections from nodes to master do NOT go through the NAT gateway. How would I find out the IP of the master?

Comment: You can find the IP of the master by running kubectl get ep. The "kubernetes" endpoint is the IP for your master's endpoint.

Comment: @PatrickW So it works! By adding a new route rule that "all traffic to master node should go through the default gateway rather than NAT". Now "kubectl logs" and "kubectl exec" continue working when NAT is on. This really should have been mentioned in https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/special-configurations

Comment: glad to hear the route works. Google actually has [NAT configuration specifically for GKE](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/using-a-nat-gateway-with-kubernetes-engine) which mentions the additional route

Answer (score 0):

It uses the `kube-proxy` to connect to the nodes and from there look at the logs in the containers as say `docker logs <container-name>` would do it. Then it proxies the output back to wherever you are running `kubectl` from.

Kubernetes uses a lot of iptables and routing in all its nodes so any change that you'd make to the instances where it's running would affect how the components talk to each other. Check if that "no-ip" tag made it change/add/remove firewall rules where your Kubernetes nodes are running.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

as Patrick mentioned,You need a new route rule that will help all traffic to master node, through the default gateway rather than NAT. Please follow this [NAT configuration specifically for GKE](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/using-a-nat-gateway-with-kubernetes-engine) which mentions the additional route.

kubectl logs interacts with the k8s api-server on your master, the master then retrieves logs from the container (effectively running docker logs on the node) and sends the info back to you. Anytime you run a kubectl command it interacts with the API server on the master. The master then connects to the node using SSH. You can also find the IP of the master by running kubectl get endpoint. The "kubernetes" endpoint is the IP for your master's endpoint.